# why is (WebView) in brackets in android

Tags: android

My background is mainly web design using JS HTML and CSS writing simple apps - nothing professional. I have recent had the urge to learn a bit about Android development. I quickly came across the below line. I understand defining the variable as a webview etc, but I don't understand why '(WebView)', in brackets, is used in the statement.

```
WebView browser; 
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
```

I can only imagine its something to do with android as I haven't come across it in JS before. Any help or info on where I can read up on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's Java and those () brackets used to `cast` things

Comment: Um... You're aware that Android is Java and not JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is type casting.

```
WebView browser;
```

In the above line, you are declaring `browser` as an object of `WebView`.

So it can hold only `WebView`

So, in the below line, you are setting the type to `WebView` in order to prevent error if the `findViewById(R.id.webkit);` return otherwise

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
```

This is actually a Java feature.

You can read more about it in [Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: The fact I have been looking for JS documentation to cover this might be why I cant find it. Thanks for the info and ill read up on it :)

Answer (score 0):

That is what we call as type casting!

**Code:**

```
WebView browser; 
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
```

**Explanation:**

You are assigning value to the instance of `WebView`(i.e., `browser`) by typecasting the `View` from your design(`.xml` file) to `WebView`. Because, `.java` file should recognize what `view` is the `webKit` in the design.